# Окраїни районів міста: Північно-Східний Бруклін чи північно-східний Бруклін?

Tags: правопис

Як правильно перекласти Northeast Brooklyn? Бруклін — це район міста Нью-Йорк. А Northeast — його північно-східна частина.

У правописі 2015 ([параграф 38](https://pravopys.net/#search=38)) сказано:

> 7. Назви сторін світу: за́хід, пі́вдень, пі́вніч, схід, норд-о́ст, півде́нний за́хід — звичайно пишуться з малої літери. Якщо під цими
>      назвами розуміються країни чи народи, тоді вони пишуться з великої
>      літери: Дале́кий Схід, За́хідна Украї́на, краї́ни За́ходу, куро́рти
>      Пі́вдня, наро́ди Пі́вночі, Півде́нне Полі́сся, Півні́чна Букови́на,
>      Схід проки́нувся.

У правописі 2019 ([параграф 50](https://2019.pravopys.net/sections/50/)) уточнюється про регіони:

> 10. Назви сторін світу: за́хід, пі́вдень, пі́вніч, схід, норд-о́ст, півде́нний за́хід — звичайно пишемо з малої букви. Якщо ці назви
>       вживаються на означення країн, народів, регіонів, тоді їх пишемо з
>       великої букви: краї́ни За́ходу, Дале́кий Схід, За́хідна Украї́на,
>       наро́ди Пі́вночі, Півде́нне Полі́сся, Півні́чна Букови́на.

Але Northeast Brooklyn — це не є офіційна географічна назва району. Район називається просто Бруклін, а Northeast Brooklyn — лише його північно-східна частина. Так само як південно-західна Троєщина.

То як усе ж таки правильно: Північно-Східний Бруклін чи північно-східний Бруклін?

Answer (score 1):

Якщо коротко, то зазвичай пишуть ***с**хід Європи*, ***с**хідна частина Європи*, але ***С**хідна Європа*. Хоча «Східна Європа» — це теж не офіційна назва. І «Далекий Схід», «Західна Україна», «Південне Полісся», «Північна Буковина» (приклади з правопису) — теж не офіційні назви (у деяких випадках це навіть неконкретні назви, тобто означувані території не мають чітких меж). Однак це назви, що з певних причин набули популярності.

Тобто я вважаю: ***північний схід Брукліну (Брукліна)*, *північно-східна частина Брукліну (Брукліна)*, але *Північно-Східний Бруклін***.

P. S.: Іноді пишуть *західна Україна*, *східна Європа* тощо, але в десятки (для окремих словосполучень — навіть у сотні) раз рідкіше — я не знаю, вважати це альтернативним варіантом чи помилкою.

P. P. S.: У [«ГРАК»](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8)-8:

- `(Західн|Східн|Північн|Південн).* Укра[йї]н.*` — [11169](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac8&queryselector=phraserow&phrase=(%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD|%D0%A1%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD|%D0%9F%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD|%D0%9F%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD).*+%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0[%D0%B9%D1%97]%D0%BD.*),
  `(західн|східн|північн|південн).* Укра[йї]н.*` — [773](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac8&queryselector=phraserow&phrase=(%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD|%D1%81%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD|%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD|%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD).*+%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0[%D0%B9%D1%97]%D0%BD.*);
- `(Західн|Східн|Північн|Південн).* [ЕЄ]вроп.*` — [11210](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac8&queryselector=phraserow&phrase=(%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD|%D0%A1%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD|%D0%9F%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD|%D0%9F%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD).*+[%D0%95%D0%84]%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF.*),
  `(західн|східн|північн|південн).* [ЕЄ]вроп.*` — [617](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac8&queryselector=phraserow&phrase=(%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD|%D1%81%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD|%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD|%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD).*+[%D0%95%D0%84]%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF.*);
- `(Західн|Східн|Північн|Південн).* [А-Я].*` — [45284](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac8&queryselector=phraserow&phrase=(%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD|%D0%A1%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD|%D0%9F%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD|%D0%9F%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD).*+[%D0%90-%D0%AF].*),
  `(західн|східн|північн|південн).* [А-Я].*` — [6795](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac8&queryselector=phraserow&phrase=(%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD|%D1%81%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD|%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD|%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD).*+[%D0%90-%D0%AF].*).

Comment: «іноді пишуть», «зазвичай пишуть» *[citation needed]*

Comment: Дякую за відповідь. А чи є десь джерела з прикладами вживання окраїн районів міст (у західних країнах)? Можливо, не Бруклін, а щось схоже. Скажімо, Мангеттен, Чайнатаун, Челсі.

Comment: Ну, от, наприклад, [усі словосполучення вигляду «Західне/Східне/Північне/Південне Щось»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/freqs?q=aword,%22(Західн|Східн|Північн|Південн).*%22+%22[А-Я].*%22&fcrit=word/e+0~0>0) (там я на якійсь зі сторінок знайшов зокрема [Окленд](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%22(Західн|Східн|Північн|Південн).*%22+%22Окленд.*%22&default_attr=word)).

Comment: @bytebuster, на основі ГРАК-8. У принципі можна твердження зробити гіперпосиланнями, але мені було ліньки.

Comment: @Sasha мені здається, можна просто в тексті відповіді сказати, звідки дані, без гіперпосилання.